# Status Bar Disappeared on XR (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

The status bar has disappeared on some viewControllers!  The "ears" around the notch, and some space below, are now covered with a sold black bar.

I am using a UITabBarController with 4 viewControllers - the status bar appears on two of them, but not the other two.

It just began happening, and occurs in both portrait and landscape.  What might be causing this?  What might I have done?  (Xcode 10.1, XR simulator)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a few thoughts. First, when in landscape the notch should be on the left/right side - are you saying it isn't, or that this "black bar" is still at the top? Second, are you using (1) auto layout constraints and (2) safe areas of these two view controller views? I'm really thinking the latter is the actual issue. Check that your constraints on the ZVC base views match between those that work versus those that aren't.

Comment: Figured it out - thank you for looking!  My first thought was the safe areas since I had been playing with the constraints.  And since I have been careful to use ````safeAreaLayoutGuide```` it was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally changed the background color to .clear by un-commenting it in the VC's class:

```
    //backgroundColor = .red
    backgroundColor = .blue
    backgroundColor = .clear
```

Which also explains why it happened in two of the viewControllers (the two that use that class).

Though I am not sure why .clear makes the status bar black...

Comment: I *think* if you create a new project and run it - with no views or background color - on a device you'll either get a completely black screen or a white one, depending on dark or light mode.